# Javascript regex to remove Specific strings in beginning and end

Tags: javascript, string, variables

Base on the following string

```
for(var i=0;i<${MyVar}.length;i++){ alert(${MyVar}[i]); }
```

How can I remove the `${` at the beginning and end `}` in the end of string, so it can be used like this?

```
for(var i=0;i<MyVar.length;i++){ alert(MyVar[i]); }
```

I'm creating a component in my system to inject javascript code and execute, but i need to replace the system variables to javascript variable.

```
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.innerHTML = "var ... "; // variables
  script.innerHTML += transformCode(code); // code injected
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].append(script);
```

[image]

I already did the part of creating the variables from an array of objects, something like that:

```
function variableTransform(variables){
  var html = "";
  for(var key in variables) {
    html += "var "+key+" ='"+variables[key]+"';\n";
  }
  //alert(html);
  return html;
}
```

Comment: Trying to parse JavaScript code with regex is going to keep you busy. Chances are you will keep finding new patterns where the regex will match too much or too little.

Comment: So do you have a list of all the variables and their values? There is probably a better way to handle this....

Comment: yes, I have all

Comment: If you have just the variables by themselves as a string, you could just do ```replace(/\${|}/g, "")```

Comment: @isherwood I explained up there, I have to create a component that accepts javascript code that will take the system variables and transform it into js code to be executed.

Comment: i think @ajarrow answer my question, i'm doing some tests :)

Comment: @sealabr It wont work because it matches the last } as well on the function.

Comment: yeah not worked :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
.replace(/\$\{(\w+)\}/g, '$1')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/SvKMEj/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \}                       '}'
```

JavaScript:

```js
const text = 'for(var i=0;i<${MyVar}.length;i++){ alert(${MyVar}[i]); if(${FooBar}) { ${Bazz}(); } }';
console.log(text.replace(/\$\{(\w+)\}/g, '$1'));
```

Comment: This is the way to go. I had figured out how to remove the whole var (```${myVar}```) but I couldn't figure out how to put ```nyVar``` back in. But I didn't know about the slick ```$1```. :)

Comment: thanks, is to ask to much to remove the "-" in variables? a new scenario appeared.... ${My-Var} to MyVar. thanks again

Comment: @sealabr Use `/\$\{([\w-]+)\}/g` or `/\$\{(\w+(?:-\w+)*)\}/g`

Comment: regex found the occurrence, but not replaced :( :( :( https://regex101.com/r/njCfKs/1/

Comment: @sealabr If you need to support one-hyphen variable names, use `.replace(/\$\{(\w+)(?:-(\w+))?\}/g, '$1$2')`, see  https://regex101.com/r/njCfKs/2. Otherwise, use `.replace(/\$\{([\w-]+)\}/g, (_, $1) => $1.replace(/-/g, ''))`

Answer (score 0):

They are string literals so let it do the work for you.

```js
var variables = 'var FooBar = "Chicken"; var Bazz = "Tuna"; var MyVar = "Dog";';
var codeString = "for(var i=0;i<${MyVar}.length;i++){ alert(${MyVar}[i]); if(${FooBar}) { ${Bazz}(); } }";

var temp = (new Function(variables + " return `" + codeString + "`")());

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: I need to keep the variables and not exchange them for the strings       

var script = document.createElement("script");
var variables = 'var Bazz = "Tuna";';
var codeString = "alert(${Bazz});";
var temp = (new Function(variables + " return `" + codeString + "`")());
script.innerHTML += temp;
console.log(script.innerHTML);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].append(script);

ReferenceError: Tuna is not defined

Comment: the result: <script>alert(Tuna);</script>

Comment: Well that is a bit different that your original idea....